# Ascii code lost when passed to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, dhtml

I have a string being passed on from code to client side.
where it becomes part of a hyperlinked column of a table which passes it to a javascript function when clicked
but somehow, i can see the html of table being formed, it has `&#9;` for line breaks in the string(At least when i see in the text visualiser) and looks like a space when viewed in html visualiser.
but when passed to function on clicking the hyperlink. it looses the space it was meant to have for `&#9;`

The hyperlink part of the table is as below

```
<A id=btnTest href="javascript:TestFunction('You have 2 apples, of which&#9;0 are fresh&#9;4 are rotten&#9;0 are smelly. </A>
```

when passed to TestFunction string becomes

```
You have 2 apples, of which0 are fresh4 are rotten0 are smelly
```

Comment: Add the relevant code so that we can see.

Comment: <A id=btnTest href="javascript:TestFunction('You have 2 apples, of which&#9;0 are fresh&#9;4 are rotten&#9;0 are smelly. </A>

Comment: I can't replicate your problem with the edits included... It logs fine. http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/YCrjm/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new line you should use `&#10;` or `&NewLine;` as denoted in [W3's Character Entity Reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref). `&#9;` is a tab, not a new line.

If we test this by logging the following:

```html
Hello,&#10;World!
```

We get this result:

```
Hello,
World!
```

Comment: Hi, I realised the string is manipulated internally when passed from the service to client side.

Comment: It had 

\r\n\t


\r\n\t


\r\n\t


\r\n\r\n


\r\n\r\n

\r\n\r\n

Comment: but when reached client side, It was all a different code set.Plus i dont understand why is the tab code getting lost when passed

Comment: The tab isn't getting lost. I linked you to this in my comment on your question: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/YCrjm.